# windows 10 laptop waking up from sleep randomly source : "power button"

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, power-management

I have a GL552vw laptop, recently about a month ago I noticed that it keeps waking up at random times at night, so end up with reduced or no battery if I need it - it's a gaming laptop and itdrains battery fast, so I'd like to keep it full for when I need it

I think it's recently started doing this, I've had this machine for about 4 months

I've seen some other solutions on the internet, 
I've disable wake on LAN 
for WIFI, it's already greyed out

the wake up source is always "power button" in the event logs

sometimes it wakes up a minute after lid close event,
sometimes it wakes up after 2 hours

it then goes to sleep after 20 mins as specified in the balanced power scheme
today I checked it woke and slept like 4-5 times

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is it connected to an ethernet cable at all?

Comment: No, i pack it up in my bag when i leave work ,  i have noticed it waking up when it was on my side table next to the bed as well, so it isn't the power button being pressed

Comment: Is an update available? I've noticed that my Windows 10 machine will do something similiar to this when an update is available.  I think it's because its still downloading the update files.  This happened with wake on LAN and those options disabled.

Comment: Do you have 'Allow Wake Timers' enabled?  You can check this in the Power Options Control Panel, in the Advanced Power Settings: Sleep>Allow Wake Timers.  If it's enabled, set it to "On Battery: Disable".

Comment: I have tried everything these last couple of weeks - I've given up , no updates pending and still keeps waking on power source almost every 3 hours or so (or at random times) - I've just set it to hibernate on lid close - at least my battery is still there when I need it